# Is there a more optimal way to change multiple classes and ids with javascript than this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a meal customisation feature on a website where the customer can choose a variety of different ingredients to configure their meal. I have the back end working perfectly, but I'm having a bit of trouble with the front end.

I've used a variety of id's, classes and functions to create a hover overlay and then apply a border around the food images once they are clicked (selected) but it's quite a long method. It works, but as there are a lot more ingredients than this (another 30) I'm a bit worried about the functions getting too long.

**HTML**

```
<img id="food" onclick="select()" src="https://website.com/uploads/2020/03/Curried-Chicken-Breast-1-scaled.jpg" style="width:250px;">

<img id="food1" onclick="select1()" src="https://website.com/uploads/2020/03/Curried-Chicken-Breast-1-scaled.jpg" style="width:250px;">
```

**CSS:**

```
#food:hover, #food1:hover, #food2:hover, #food3:hover, #food4:hover, #food5:hover, #food6:hover, #food7:hover{
    filter: brightness(75%); !important;
}

.selected {
  border: 3px solid #186472 !important;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function select(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select1(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select2(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select3(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select4(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select5(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select6(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.add('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.remove('selected');
}

function select7(){
    document.getElementById("food").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food1").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food2").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food3").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food4").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food5").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food6").classList.remove('selected');
    document.getElementById("food7").classList.add('selected');
}
</script>
```

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpZSJ.jpg)

Comment: Just some hints: use a common class (`.food`) instead of numbered ids, use `.addEventListener()` and make use of `this` in the event handler, use a loop to remove `.selected`

Comment: ... + keep book of the currently active element in a variable, it's easy to refer it when the class needs to be removed.

Comment: You don't need to store the active one actually... just select the ones that have the class "selected" (technically there should only be 1 at a time) and remove the class, then add it to whichever was clicked.

Comment: @LaurentS. Yes, but it's really easy and cheap to _"keep book of the currently active element(s)"_ escpecially when the browser does all the hard work: `const selectedElements = document.getElementsByClassName("selected");`

Comment: @Andreas > Yes it's cheap, but by doing it you still have a risk that the variable is not updated for some edge case. Also regarding your example, you're not supposed to re-assign a const variable so this would throw an error I think.

Comment: @LaurentS. `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a [live HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection): _"An `HTMLCollection` in the HTML DOM is live; it is **automatically updated when the underlying document is changed**."_

Comment: @Andreas Thanks you for this info. My comment was all wrong then :-) Although basically my suggestion was to do exactly the same, without the constant :-)

Comment: Javascript isn't necessary for this. Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60529324/#answer-60530035) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `JS` comments:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var foods = document.getElementsByClassName('food'); // To get length of all food pictures.
        for(var i = 0; i < foods.length; i++) { // for loop to create click function on each image.
            var food = foods[i]; // get current class index.
            food.onclick = function() { // DOM onclick function.
                Array.from(foods).forEach(function(e){e.classList.remove('selected')}) // remove 'selected' class from all 'food' classes. 
                this.classList.add('selected'); // add selected class to current '.food'.
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.food:hover {
    filter: brightness(75%); !important;
}

.selected {
  border: 3px solid #186472 !important;
}
```

```html
<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">

<img class="food" src="https://picsum.photos/200">
```

Comment: @Zerion this method only lets you select one item at a time.

Comment: Why `document.querySelectorAll('.food')` when there's already `var foods = document.getElementsByClassName('food')`?

Comment: @Sean yes you right, i think this is what he want. If you want to select more than one item at a time tell me.

Comment: @Andreas because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a HTML collection not an array, i can use it like `Array.from(foods).forEach(function(e){...}` but i don't prefer this.

Comment: If you would add a loop you wouldn't have to re-query the DOM on every click to get the `.food` items.

Comment: @Andreas mmm.. yeah you right, I've changed my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking users to select items from a series of things, you should consider using radio buttons. Using radio buttons will make things easier from a code standpoint by removing the need to set the selected state with javascript, and it will be more accessible for users.

Here's one way to approach it **with no javascript needed**, making use of the [`:checked` CSS pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) and [CSS adjacent sibling combinator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) to add a red border to checked food items.

```css
.food {
  display: inline-block;
}
.food input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.food img {
  border: 5px solid white;
}
.food input:checked + label img {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.food input:not(:checked) + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.food input:not(:checked) + label:hover img {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<div class="food">
  <input type="radio" id="food1" name="food" value="food1" />
  <label for="food1"><img alt="food1" src="https://placehold.it/100/100/?text=food1"/></label>
</div>
<div class="food">
  <input type="radio" id="food2" name="food" value="food2" />
  <label for="food2"><img alt="food2" src="https://placehold.it/100/100/?text=food2"/></label>
</div>
<div class="food">
  <input type="radio" id="food3" name="food" value="food3" />
  <label for="food3"><img alt="food3" src="https://placehold.it/100/100/?text=food3"/></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could aways make it as a function.

```
function select( val ){

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
        document.getElementById(`food${i}`).classList.remove('selected');
    } 

    document.getElementById(`food${val}`).classList.add('selected');
}

// select(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes like selector:

```
<img class="food" onclick="select(this)" src="https://website.com/uploads/2020/03/Curried-Chicken-Breast-1-scaled.jpg" style="width:250px;">

<img class="food" onclick="select1(this)" src="https://website.com/uploads/2020/03/Curried-Chicken-Breast-1-scaled.jpg" style="width:250px;">
```

JavaScript will looks like this:

```
<script>
$food_els = document.getElementByClassName("food");
function select(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $food_els.length; i++) {
        if ($food_els[i] == e) {
            $food_els[i].classList.add("selected");
        }
        else {
            $food_els[i].classList.remove("selected");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: And what's with `select1`?

Comment: You could also reduce the "complexity" of your loop if you remove the `.selected` class from every element in the list. Then just add it to `e` after the loop.

Comment: The least complex would be to not loop on a bunch of elements while knowing only 1 of them is supposed to have that class. Sure you won't see the difference in most cases, but as your number of elements grows the impact on performance will become more and more visible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use
 - a better CSS
 - the div for group images
 - **event delegation**

**HTML**

```
<div id="Group-Images">
  <img id="food1" src="Curried-Chicken-Breast-1-scaled.jpg" >
  <img id="food2" src="Curried-Chicken-Breast-2-scaled.jpg" >
  <img id="food3" src="Curried-Chicken-Breast-3-scaled.jpg" >
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Group-Images > img {
  width: 250px;
}
#Group-Images > img:hover {
  filter: brightness(75%) !important;
}
#Group-Images > img.selected {
  border: 3px solid #186472 !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
const GroupImages = document.getElementById('Group-Images')
  ,   AllImages   = GroupImages.querySelectorAll('img')
  ;
GroupImages.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('img')) return

  // console.log( e.target.id) // --> food1, food2,... foodN

  AllImages.forEach(imh=>
    {
    if (img===e.target) { img.classList.add('selected')   }
    else                { img.classList.remove('selected') }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Why the `<div>`? What if the layout doesn't allow such a change?

Comment: There's a "convention" that only constructor functions that have to be used with the `new` operator should start with a capital letter.

Comment: @Andreas  a `<div>` or anything else you want, but event delegation needs a parent element to catch any events of their child elements